# tmux new-window --- wait until session is up?

Tags: tmux, background-process

I am doing the following thing (this is just an example, commads are more complex):

```
xterm -fa "Inconsolata" -e tmux new-session -s alpha &
disown %%
tmux new-window -t alpha bash
tmux new-window -t alpha zsh
```

...which works perfectly when I type it in the terminal, giving me an xterm with a tmux session with three windows. BUT if I put the thing in a script, it will stop working with;

```
 no server running on /tmp/tmux-1153/default
 no server running on /tmp/tmux-1153/default
```

error, and just one window in the new `tmux` session `alpha`.

After a bit of experiments, I discovered that it *will* work again if I add a

```
sleep 5
```

(or similar) between the `disown` and the `tmux new-window` command. Clearly,
the xterm has not finished to set-up before this command is run, and so `tmux new-window` is run before the session is created unless I put a delay there.

It works, but it's not elegant. Is there a way to tell `tmux` to wait until the session `alpha` is up?

Comment: Why not just start the window with the session: `new  -s alpha -n alpha bash`?

Comment: @jasonwryan I tried, but it's not working for my case --- I really want three windows in the new sessions...

Comment: Three? You are only calling one in your example...

Comment: @jasonwryan you're right, I've simplified this too much. Corrected. However, in the first case, I had two windows (the first one launched together with the `xterm`, and the second one opened by the `tmux` command)

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609192/how-to-set-up-tmux-so-that-it-starts-up-with-specified-windows-opened/5753059#5753059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Use the `sleep` method. I see nothing really wrong about using `sleep` apart from sometimes failing if you choose a too short time. To fool-proof it, use

   ```
   while ! tmux has-session; do sleep 1; done
   ```

   or

   ```
   while ! tmux has-session -t alpha; do sleep 1; done
   ```
2. Use something like [`xtoolwait`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xtoolwait1.html) that starts an X client (your terminal emulator) in the background and returns when it has mapped its window.

If you go with the second option (which may be best), remember to remove the `&` at the end of the command starting your terminal, and it also becomes unnecesary to `disown` the job.

The command becomes:

```
xtoolwait xterm -fa "Inconsolata" -e tmux new-session -s alpha
tmux new-window -t alpha bash
```

If `xtoolwait` is not already installed on your Unix, it's likely available as a package (it's been around for *ages*). Use your package manager of choice to install it.

**EDIT**: From comments it seems as if `tmux` takes too long to spawn after the terminal has mapped its window even if `xtoolwait` is being used.  So in this situation, I would go with looping over a `sleep 1` call until the wanted `tmux` session exists.

Comment: Hmmm... seems not packaged anymore. Found here: https://github.com/dlitz/xtoolwait, testing... (does not compile. More testing needed. Umphhh...)

Comment: Ok. It *almost* work. `xtoolwait` will wait until the xterm is mapped, but not until the `tmux` is up. So I can use a smaller `sleep`, but I still have to use a `sleep` (in my new example, it fails the first `tmux`, then the second succeed...

Comment: @Rmano `while ! tmux has-session; do sleep 1; done`.  Answer updated, and I'll add more soon.

Comment: Yep, that works. The `while` with `tmux has-session -t alpha` (I have other sessions around) is doing the trick. I was even starting to look into some `inotify` trick on the socket, but this is more straightforward. Thanks!